# Como salvar um ou mais campos no banco de dados usando o Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Estou utilizando um código em Vue.js que funciona da seguinte forma se eu selecionar um checkbox eu conisgo selecionar o combobox, se eu selecionar o segundo checkbox, aparece o segundo combobox e consigo selecionar também o que tem no combobox.

**Minha pergunta é**: Se eu selecionar um checkbox consigo salvar no banco o que está no combobox ok, mas e se eu seleciono os dois ao mesmo tempo não estou conseguindo. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer? Caso eu seleciono os dois campos quero enviar os dois combobox preenchidos para o banco de dados. Alguém poderia me ajudar fazendo favor? Obrigado.

```js
var app = new Vue({ 
   el: '#check', 
   data: { 
     checks: [ 
     {label: '1 molho' , values: ['Rose' , 'Molho de Frango'] , check:false}, 
        {label: '2 molhos' , values: ['Rose' , 'Molho de Frango'] , check:false} 
     ]
   } 
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="check">
  <div v-for="check in checks" >
    <label >{{check.label}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-on:click="check.check = check.check == false ? true : false">
    <select v-if="check.check" name="tipo_molho">
      <option v-for="value in check.values " v-bind:value="value" >{{value}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem que postar o código referente ao problema, para obter maior ajuda!

Comment: <div id="check">
    <div v-for="check in checks" >
        <label >{{check.label}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" v-on:click="check.check = check.check == false ? true : false">
        <select  v-if="check.check" name="tipo_molho"> 
            <option v-for="value in check.values "  v-bind:value="value" >{{value}}
        </select>
    </div>   
</div>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
  el: '#check',
  data: {
    checks: [
        {label: '1 molho' , values: ['Rose' , 'Molho de Frango']  , check:false},
        {label: '2 molhos' , values:  ['Rose' , 'Molho de Frango']  , check:false}
    ]
  }
})
</script>

Comment: Esse é o código o que devo ajustar ou implementar para que isso funcione e os dois combobox sejam enviados para o banco caso eu selecione os dois?

Comment: Mas qual é o problema? Dá algum erro no console? Está salvando como? Pois pelo Html e Js não dá para saber o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Então no banco só tem um único campo que é tipo_molho aí quando seleciono só um molho salva ok no banco, quando seleciono os dois molhos ou seja os dois combobox ai salva só o primeiro molho. Como faço para salvar os dois tipos de molho no banco? Por exemplo se a pessoa quiser só um molho salva no banco, mas e se ela quiser dois tipos de molho ou seja selecionando os dois combobox como faço para salvar esses dois tipos de molho no banco usando a mesma div??? Vou ter que criar uma condiçao ou tem como criar mais um name na div e aí crio mais um campo lá no banco de dados, por ex: tipo_molho2?

Comment: Ou melhor no mesmo <select>. Tentei criar outro campo e coloquei dois names dentro do select mas não funcionou, não está salvando os dois combobox do mesmo select no banco de dados